# Do I need an impact driver for driving concrete screws?

Tags: concrete, screws, drill

I'll shortly need to bolt some shelving and a power rack down into my garages concrete floor.

I'm planning on using concrete screws so that I can remove them later if I want to move anything around.

I've already got a consumer grade / home diy brushless drill driver.

Obviously I'll need to buy a hammer drill to drill the holes - but will I need an impact driver to drive the concrete screws, or can I get away with using the drill driver?

Comment: This is likely a matter of opinion. An impact driver might make it easier but it should certainly be possible with a drill and some elbow grease, assuming the pilot hole is properly sized. If it's not, an impact driver isn't gonna help you, either.

Comment: You can use the "expansion anchor" or a "chemical anchor" to meet your need. Both do not require an impact driver for installation. A regular hammer is all you need.

Comment: There's no opinion involved here - concrete anchors were installed long before impact drivers were developed. The simple answer is "No".

Comment: Concrete screws are a good excuse to buy a big thick regular Phillips head screw driver.    Then you don't need to worry about some sort of gear or motor getting messed up if you need to really lean into it.

Comment: @Willk Phillips head screws are not realy appropriate if the screws are difficult to turn

Comment: @FreeMan And much weaker people do DIY today than 50-100 years ago.

Comment: @jstola - I am curious what screwheads are most appropriate for difficult to turn screws.

Comment: @Willk Torx, external hex, internal hex, square — any of the screwheads designed to retain the driver rather than camming out under load (which is what Phillips screws do by design)

Answer (score 5):

A socket wrench is a good tool for driving concrete screws.  Your hammer-drill might do the job, but if not, don't rush out to buy an impact driver if you have a socket set handy.

Always buy the hex-head concrete screws.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "concrete screw" is sufficient to anchor the heavy-duty racks. I recommend using the "wedge anchor" instead.

Wedge anchors are fasteners designed for use in masonry/concrete base material that provides holding power through expansion. **The anchor is inserted in a predrilled hole compress and then exerts force to create the holding power.** A regular hammer is sufficient to force the anchor into the concrete slab.

[image] From HD

**Note, the technical datasheet is for your estimating purpose. You shall check with the supplier for the strength and method of installation for the specific product you have selected.**

[image]

Comment: Installation note: Drill hole 1" deeper, tap in with nut on bolt to prevent overdriving. After removing equipment replace nut, draw bolt out as far as possible, remove nut, fold bolt with hammer and break off bolt, drive remaining bolt deep into hole, fill with grout.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I'm a bit confused. You say "Installation note", then "after removing equipment". Are the rest of the instructions for hiding the remains of the bolt after the equipment has been removed/relocated, or is that still part of the installation notes? Maybe it's just that my coffee hasn't kicked in yet this morning...